# Proof that $\mathbb{R}$ is not countable

Tags: real-analysis, integration, continuity, real-numbers, cardinals

I know that this proof may sound ridiculous, but I'm really curious to find out if it's logically correct(and whether there are some circularities). Since $|[0,1]|=|\mathbb{R}|$, we have  to simply show that $[0,1]$ is not countable. This theorem holds:

> $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R} \\ \text{Let } D_f \text{ be the set of discontinuities of }f \\ |D_f|\leq\aleph_0 \Rightarrow f \text{ is Riemann-integrable in }[a,b] $

Now I can define the Dirichlet function in $[0,1]$:
$\chi(x)=\begin{cases} 1 \ \ \text{if }x\in\mathbb{Q} \\ 0 \ \ \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$

Clearly $D_\chi=[0,1]$. By contradiction, if $|[0,1]|=\aleph_0$, then it would mean that $\chi$ is Riemann-integrable in $[0,1]$, but it's not: this is a contadiction!

So $|[0,1]|>\aleph_0$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is correct and as far as I can see this does not contain circularities. Perhaps it is a little cleaner to use contraposition instead of contradiction though.

FYI, a more general statement than the one you described holds. Let $f: [a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded function. Then $f$ is Riemann-integrable if and only if $D_f$ has Lebesgue measure $0$. Of course, if $D_f$ is countable then it has Lebesgue measure $0$ since singeltons don't have a length.

Comment: "Then f is Riemann-integrable if and only if Df has Lebesgue measure 0" Is this true? Is the Indicator function $ I_{\mathbb{Q}}$ is Rieman integrable?

Comment: @BokaPeer Here $D_f= [0,1]$ has measure $1$, so it is not Riemann integrable. It is Lebesgue-integrable though.

Comment: Thanks. I misread something, and so, I was confused. Thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome! Glad I could help.

Comment: The indicator function of $\mathbb Q$ is discontinuous at every point.  Check the definition of "continuous".

Comment: @GEdgar Sure,  nobody said otherwise?